# Calculus of residue question

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Hi I have some questions in regard to calculus of residue and its basic applications.

I was asked,

compute

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D(0,8)} \frac{\cot z}{(z-6i)^2+64}dz$$

And here are my thoughts,

I factored the bottom as $$(z+2i)(z-14i)$$

which implies we have two simple poles , $z=-2i$ and $z=14i$

Using the formula for the residues,

I came up with

$$a_{-1}=\cot(-2i)/(-16i)$$

and $$b_{-1}=\cot (14i)/16i$$

which led me to an answer of

$$\frac{\cot(14i)-\cot(2i)}{16i}$$

However, I have two questions concerns.

My big issue is that this is incorrect according to the solution in the book,

the solution given is $$-\cot(2i)/16i+(1/28)+1/((\pi-6i)^2+64)+1/((-\pi-6i)^2+64)+1/((2\pi-6i)^2+64)+1/((-2\pi-6i)^2+64)$$

so that is confusing to me.

And my second question is, where does the fact that our path is the boundary on the circle of radius 8 come into play? Does it just mean that we need to assure that our poles are in this enclosure?

Can anyone help find my mistake/explain how the correct answer was obtained.

Update: Thanks, it is all cleared up now. Incase anyone is interested, the mistake was a very simple one, being that I forgot to consider the poles that arose from the cot term

Comment: $\cot z$ has poles also. Incidentally, $z=14i$ isn't in the contour.

Comment: Ah so I will have to consider the poles of cot. and does that mean i simply can ignore z=14i?

Comment: $z=14i$ playes no role, but values where $cotz$ equals zero within your radius, do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
I =\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D(0,8)} \frac{\cot z}{(z-6i)^2+64}\,dz
\end{align}

$$f(z) = \frac{\cot z}{(z+2i)(z-14i)} = \frac{\cos z}{\sin z(z+2i)(z-14i)}$$

The poles in the contour are at $-2i$ (as you found) and $n\pi$ for $|n| \le 2$.

$$\operatorname*{Res}_{z=-2i}f(z) = \cot(2i)/(16i)$$

$$\operatorname*{Res}_{z=n\pi} f(z) = \frac{1}{(n\pi-6i)^2+64}$$

Then, just sum as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

## Hint:

$$\cot(z)=\frac{\cos(z)}{\sin(z)}$$

Which has simple poles everywhere $\sin(z)=0$.

Secondly, when applying the residue theorem, we only consider points that are enclosed within the contour.

Together, one should arrive at

$$z\in\{-2i,-\pi,-2\pi,0,\pi,2\pi\}$$

Comment: Thanks, I know its a bit late but I am a bit confused. How do we know to consider both the negative and positive radian values? Because arent they the same? ie why 0 and 2pi, and -2pi ?

Comment: @Quality both are within the region we are looking at and they both cause division by $0$, hence they are poles.